# Subtract column with the next column in a different row

Tags: php, mysql, subtraction

Is there a way to subtract two column in different row using PHP or MySQL?

```
|MATRIX NO|DESCRIPTIONS                   |DEBIT  | CREDIT  |
|CA10045  |STUDIES FEES                   |500.00 | 0.00    |
|CA10045  |OUTSTANDING LAST SEMESTER FEES |300.00 | 0.00    |
|CA10045  |STUDIES FEES                   |0.00   | 300.00  |
|CA10045  |OUTSTANDING LAST SEMESTER FEES |0.00   | 100.00  |
```

Row 1 DEBIT STUDIES FEES deduct with Row 3 STUDIES FEES CREDIT

Comment: Debit and credit are really the same thing... differences on a balance.  Make one negative, and then you can have a rollup.  If you don't need to do this at the data level though, you might consider handling the total balance display in your PHP application.

Comment: Actually I want deduct debit with credit based on the descriptions.

Comment: @Rahul What's there to join?  It looks like each column as it stands now will only have a debit or credit, so do something like `SELECT DEBIT-CREDIT`

Comment: can't be in group by?

Comment: @Brad it's actually part of my project that I need to deduct debit with credit base on the descriptions

Comment: @Brad, Yes absolutely correct and that's why removed my comment.

Comment: @Brad `SELECT DEBIT-CREDIT` will not work as desired here as well, because that works on a per-row basis … and one of debit/credit is always zero per row in the data shown.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, exactly.  You're not understanding what I'm suggesting.  As I said in my first comment, the credit and debit are the same thing.  Since the data isn't structured that way, we need to derive a column that is, which is done by simply subtracting one from the other.  Once you have that, you can easily `GROUP BY` description or whatever you need, as well as roll up everything if you want, and get the balance.

Comment: So you want to deduct credit from debit where which rows has same description value. I think you need to do this in php, mysql can't do that because you are comparing rows, not columns

Comment: Yeah, in combination with your first comment it makes total sense. (Guess the now missing comment by Rahul that you referred to threw me off here.)

Comment: I suggest update rows instead of inserting as a new row where description is equal. that is update credit or debit if description is same. then you can easily use something like select debit-credit as @CBore said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution, but here it is anyway.

```
SELECT a.matrix_no, a.descriptions, a.debit - b.credit as total
FROM (select * from matrix where debit > 0) a
INNER JOIN (select * from matrix where credit > 0) b
ON a.matrix_no = b.matrix_no AND a.descriptions = b.descriptions
```